# How to use redux toolkit in SPFX (typescript) project?

Tags: typescript, redux, spfx

I'm building some SPFX components (typescript + webpack based).

I'd like to include redux toolkit in the project, but it break compilation.

What I did :

- scaffolded the project using yo
- installed `redux` `react-redux` and `@reduxjs/toolkit` (using `pnpm` if it matters)
- followed the [Redux Toolkit TypeScript Quick Start](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript) by creating the file `store.ts` with this content :

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// ...

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
  
  }
})

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

When I try to build the project `gulp build`, it fails with a bunch of errors :

```
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(1,143): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(2,57): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(3,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(3,70): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(4,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(4,54): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/createAction.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[15:15:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.6.1_react-redux@7.2.4+react@16.9.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/createAction.d.ts(1,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
... dozens of similar lines removed ...
```

I also get VS Code complains regarding type inference:

```
The inferred type of 'store' cannot be named without a reference to '.pnpm/redux-thunk@2.3.0/node_modules/redux-thunk'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

This later error seems to be solved by installing `redux-thunk` and by adding `import 'redux-thunk'` at the beginning of the file.

How to properly setup my project ?

If it helps, here's a [repository that reproduce the error](https://github.com/stevebeauge/repro-redux-typescript-issue/blob/main/src/webparts/helloWorld/store.ts)

[Edit] Reverting to classic `npm` behave similarly (except for the file paths showing local copy of ts file instead of the linked one when using pnpm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

The root cause is due to the syntax used in react redux which requires typescript 3.8 or later.

Specifically, `import type` wasn't allow before.

The SPFX projects are scaffolded with a dependency to typescript 3.7.

The solution is then to upgrade the build tools of SPFX projects :

```
npm remove @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.7
npm install @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9 --save-dev
```

Also, have to update the `tsconfig.json` file to fix the path to the correct build tools version :

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9/includes/tsconfig-web.json",
  "compilerOptions": { .. }
}
```

Solution found in the post [Use Different Versions of TypeScript in SPFx projects](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/use-different-typescript-versions-in-sharepoint-framework-projects/)